# Invalid number string (7498) JDBC Request

Tags: sql, jdbc, jmeter, openedge, progress-4gl

I'm converting this progress statement into SQL.

```
for each usr_mstr where usr_userid matches "PRF52" exclusive-lock:
  assign usr_force_change = no.
end.
```

This is what I currently have.

```
UPDATE PUB.usr_mstr SET usr_force_change = 'false' WHERE usr_userid = 'PRF52'
```

The error that I am receiving is '[DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Invalid number string (7498)'.

A select statement for this field is working and returns the following.

```
SELECT usr_force_change FROM PUB.usr_mstr WHERE usr_userid = 'PRF52'
```

usr_force_change
false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column data type was of type 'LOGICAL'. This translates to type 'BIT' in SQL. I updated the statement to the following at it worked.

```
UPDATE PUB.usr_mstr SET usr_force_change = '0' WHERE usr_userid = 'PRF51'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose Query type as [Update Statement](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) when submit update

> Update Statement - use this for Inserts and Deletes as well